# Join string array with separator ", " and add ", and " to join the last element in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm messing around with parsing JSON with SwiftyJSON on a swift playground. My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

var partyList: [String] = []
var firstPresidentList: [String] = []

if let url = URL(string:"http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=presidents&format=json") {
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        let json = JSON(data: data)
        for i in 1...43 {
            let party = json[i]["pp"].stringValue
            let president = json[i]["nm"].stringValue
            if partyList.contains(party) {
                print("\n")
            } else {
                partyList.append(party)
                firstPresidentList.append(president)
            }
        }
        print("All the different parties of U.S. presidents included "+partyList.joined(separator: ", ")+", in that order. The first presidents of those parties were (repectively) "+firstPresidentList.joined(separator: ", ")+".")
    }
}
```

On the `print` line, I was wondering how I could join the arrays with a comma and space like I have, but add "and" before the last one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add a condition to check if your `String` collection has less than or is equal to 2 elements, if true just return the two elements joined by `" and "` otherwise drop the last element of your collection, join the elements with a separator `", "` then re add the last element with the final separator `", and "`.

You can extend `BidirectionalCollection` protocol constraining its elements to the `StringProtocol`:

> **Bidirectional collections** offer traversal backward from any valid
> index, not including a collection’s startIndex. Bidirectional
> collections can therefore offer additional operations, such as a **last
> property** that provides efficient access to the **last element** and a
> reversed() method that presents the elements in reverse order.

**Xcode 11.4 • Swift 5.2 or later**

```
extension BidirectionalCollection where Element: StringProtocol {
    var sentence: String {
        count <= 2 ?
            joined(separator: " and ") :
            dropLast().joined(separator: ", ") + ", and " + last!
    }
}
```

---

```
let elements = ["a", "b", "c"]
let sentenceFromElements = elements.sentence   // "a, b, and c"
```

---

**edit/update**

**Xcode 13+ • iOS15+**

You can use the new generic structure [`ListFormatStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/listformatstyle) with the new instance methods of Sequence called formatted:

```
let elements = ["a", "b", "c"]
let formatted = elements.formatted()  // "a, b, and c"

let names = ["Steve Jobs", "Wozniak", "Tim Cook", "Jony Ive"]
let formatted2and = names.formatted(.list(type: .and, width: .short))  // "Steve Jobs, Wozniak, Tim Cook, & Jony Ive"
let formatted2or = names.formatted(.list(type: .or, width: .short))    // "Steve Jobs, Wozniak, Tim Cook, or Jony Ive"
```

---

If you need a specific locale (fixed) like Portuguese Brasil:

```
let localeBR = Locale(identifier: "pt_BR")
let formatted2e = names.formatted(
    .list(type: .and, width: .short)
    .locale(localeBR)
)  // "Steve Jobs, Wozniak, Tim Cook e Jony Ive"
let formatted2ou = names.formatted(
    .list(type: .or, width: .short)
    .locale(localeBR)
)  // "Steve Jobs, Wozniak, Tim Cook ou Jony Ive"
```

Answer (score 21):

Since iOS 13.0+ / macOS 10.15+ Apple provides the [ListFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/listformatter). See also [here for details](https://nshipster.com/formatter/#listformatter).

Arrays can be formatted as easy as:

```
let elements = ["a", "b", "c"]
result = ListFormatter.localizedString(byJoining: elements)
```

As the function name suggests, you also get the localization for free.