# Efficient way to replace final comma with word and at end of comma delimited list in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, arraylist

If you have a list like apple,orange,lemon, you can change it to apple, orange and lemon in Objective-C using:

```
NSString *str = @"apple,orange,lemon";  
NSRange lastComma = [str rangeOfString:@"," options:NSBackwardsSearch];

if(lastComma.location != NSNotFound) {
    str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:lastComma
                                       withString: @" and"];
}
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in Swift?

I can replace the last element of the array with `'and lemon'` by converting the string into an array using

```
 var arr = str.components(separatedBy: ",")
```

But I am struggling with how to remove the last comma.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: The same approach would work with Swift, compare e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/26411635/1187415 for how to search for the last occurrence of a comma in the string.

Comment: Thanks I used the extension in the linked to answer

Comment: @user6631314 https://stackoverflow.com/a/41819176/2303865

Comment: Yes, if you want a nicely localized string, it is `NSArray <NSString *> *strings = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];` and `[NSListFormatter localizedStringByJoiningStrings:strings]` as noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62412873/1271826.