# Pull one property from multiple, specific structs in an array

Tags: swiftui

Part of my project involves comparing 4 people's scores, finding the lowest, and just outputting the name of that player. But now I need it to support multiple names, which I think I've successfully done but it outputs the entire Struct of those players. For example:

```
["AppName.Player(name: "Bob", score: 2), AppName.Player(name: "John", score: 2)]
```

while I just want `["Bob", "John"]` or preferably just `"Bob and John"`.

Heres the code, where `winnerText` controls what's displayed:

```
let players = [Player(name: "Bob", score: bobTotal), Player(name: "Ted", score: tedTotal), Player(name: "John", score: johnTotal), Player(name: "Rick", score: rickTotal)]
            
let minValue = players.min(by: { $0.score < $1.score })?.score ?? 0
let PlayersWithMinScore = players.filter { $0.score == minValue }
print(PlayersWithMinScore)

let winningPlayerIndex = players.indices.filter { players[$0].score == minValue }
print(winningPlayerIndex)
        
       
self.winnerText = "" + " won with " + "\(minValue)"
```

```
struct Player {
  let name: String
  let score: Int
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PlayersWithMinScore.map { $0.name }
```

The above will give you an array of just the names.

Borrowing  a trick from another answer ([Join string array with separator ", " and add ", and " to join the last element in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819086/join-string-array-with-separator-and-add-and-to-join-the-last-element)):

```
extension BidirectionalCollection where Element: StringProtocol {
    var sentence: String {
        count <= 2 ?
            joined(separator: " and ") :
            dropLast().joined(separator: ", ") + ", and " + last!
    }
}
```

You could then do:

```
PlayersWithMinScore.map { $0.name }.sentence
```

Giving you the names comma-separated and then last one with "and" before it (e.g. "Bob and John" or "Bob, Tom, and "John").

*A side note: in Swift, variable names usually start with a lowercase name* -- `playersWithMinScore` would be more idiomatic than `PlayersWithMinScore`