# How to display all items from a Set

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, swiftui

My app consists on an image of various foods, in which the user taps the image and adds this food into a `Set<Food>`.

I want to show all items from this Set inside the class called `Favorites`, as a: `Text("You like: \(favorites.comidas)")` but I can't manage to make it work

```
class Favorites: ObservableObject {
    var foods: Set<Food>
}
```

```
class Favorites: ObservableObject {
    var foods: Set<Food>
    
    init() {
        // load the saved data
        foods = []
    }
    
    func contains(_ food: Food) -> Bool {
        foods.contains(food)
    }
    
    func add(_ food: Food)  {
        objectWillChange.send()
        foods.insert(food)
        save()
    }
    
    func delete(_ food: Food) {
        objectWillChange.send()
        foods.remove(food)
        save()
    }
}
```

```
struct Food: Identifiable, Hashable {
    
    var id: Int
    let name: String
    let foodImage: [String]
    
    // Equatable
    static func == (lhs: Food, rhs: Food) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

---

```
@EnvironmentObject var favorites: Favorites
let food: Food

var body: Some View {

Image(food.foodImage[0])
      .onTapGesture { 
       if favorites.contains(food) {
                 favorites.delete(food)
       } else {
          favorites.add(food)
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to display a list of favourites like "You like Pizza, Chocolate and Tacos" or do you want a list of actionable buttons "You like Pizza", "You like Chocolate", "You like Tacos"?

Comment: The first one, to display a list of the food choices made by the user

Comment: You can use List + ForEach or VStack + ForEach to display the set. On a side note, it makes more sense to add and remove elements and then call objectWillChange.send()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown your `Food` structure, but I will assume it has a property, `name`.

[`ListFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/listformatter) is your friend with a task like this. Its `string(from:[])` function takes an array and returns it in a nicely formatted list.  You can use `map` to get an array of `name` strings from your set.

For the input array `["pizza","tacos","chocolate"]` it will give "pizza, tacos and chocolate"

```
var favoriteList: String {
    let formatter = ListFormatter()
    let favorites = formatter.string(from:self.favorites.foods.map{$0.name})
    return favourites ?? ""
}
```

Then you can use this function in a `Text` view:

```
Text("You like \(self.favoriteList)")
```

Note that a `Set` is unordered, so it might be nice to sort the array so that you get a consistent, alphabetical order:

```
var favoriteList: String {
    let formatter = ListFormatter()
    let favorites = formatter.string(from:self.favorites.foods.map{$0.name}.sorted())
    return favourites ?? ""
}
```

Thanks to a tip from Leo Dabus in the comments, in Xcode 13 and later you can just use `.formatted` -

```
var favoriteList: String {
    return self.favorites.foods.map{$0.name}.sorted().formatted() ?? ""

}
```

Comment: Xcode 13 or later you can simply use formatted method [Join string array with separator ", " and add ", and " to join the last element in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41819176/2303865). In this case `favorites.foods.map(\.name).formatted()`

Comment: Thanks, will try it and keep you updated. Just updated the code also. And by any chance of wanting to match this user with another user, who has the same food selections, would my code work with the class Favorites?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "match".  You could find users who have the same or significant overlap in their favourites.  You can compare sets in Swift and also use `isSubsetOf` and `isSupersetOf` to help.